# Planning to build a HPC

Tags: hpc

I start a study the best way to mount a HPC.

On my datacenter i have to initial tests 3 servers whit this settings.

- DELL PowerEdge R720
- 2 x Intel Xeon E5-2680v2 2.8GHz
- 10 x 16GB RDIMM
- XenServer 6.5

I have more at ease with CentOS. So the first question is what is the most stable CentOS for HPC?

The plane for this HPC using this tools:

- Openstack
- Torque (Resource Manager)
- Maui (Cluster Scheduler)
- Gold (Allocation Manager)
- [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/)

So if you have interest in this project please help to find de way

Comment: Hi ! I think this question is off-topic here, but there are other sites in the StackExchange network where you can ask it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about computer hardware.

Comment: I'm voting to put this question on hold as off-topic because this is a shopping question ("what should I buy?"), although I think it could be edited to be on-topic ("what should I look for in a Linux distribution for HPC?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maui and Gold are pretty much dead (check the last release date) - I'd be looking at SLURM http://slurm.schedmd.com/ if you need something free with advanced scheduling and allocation management (though they all have their pain points). If you only have three nodes though, do you need these at all? Then Torque would do just as well for simple scheduling.

If you are building a prototype for a larger system, then go SLURM and also focus on the node configuration tools, so that you know how to expand and keep things under control (some keywords to look for are Ansible/Puppet/Chef/xCat - OpenStack not yet but it depends on your workload type and if you want to expand to the cloud later)

Centos 6 is pretty stable (wait a bit for Centos 7.1 and plan an upgrade path).

Environment Modules rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Stable? Either the latest CentOS 6 or 7 should be fine from a stability perspective. I wouldn't count OpenStack as an HPC, tool, but the cloud stacks are coming along performance-wise from where they started.